# WeatherApp - React

Tags: reactjs, weather

Im building Weather App by using React + OpenWeather for educational purpose.
I use user input search method to filter based on “ CITY” which works fine.
Even the icons and background images can dynamically be changed based on temperature  ( range iD)
I use my key just like this :
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${Api_Key}`

But I would like to populate and display the weather details like 7 days forecast including hourly temp which I must use “OneCallAPI’ just like this but it did not work for me as it should
// `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid={API key}`

Is there any solution ? I appreciate the help.
Many thanks

Comment: Are you getting any response from `openweathermap`  call?

Comment: @Marvel, I was able to get this to work using the url, "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid={API key} " with the correct variable values.  Try passing the response to the console.log function to see what is being received, and use that information.